# difference between Amazon EC2 and EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, distributed-computing, amazon-emr

I'm new to Amazon cloud services. While studying about it, came across to terms `EC2 and EMR`

What I've understood so far is that, EC2 is just like an normal cloud machine and EMR is group of EC2 cloud machines. Secondly, EMR is preferred for distributed computing architecture, for ex Hadoop or Spark.

1) Why EMR is preferred for `distributed computing` ? Why not multiple EC2 instances (NOT EMR) can be used ?

2) Can anyone share more differences between EMR and EC2 to understand more ?

Thanks

Comment: The simple answer is... If you wish to use Hadoop/Spark, use Amazon EMR.

Answer (score 4):

EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud) are generic Linux or Windows servers that you can use to run anything you want. However if you want something like a distributed Hadoop cluster, or an RDBMS cluster, you will end up spending a lot of time configuring that.

EMR (Elastic Map Reduce) is, as the name implies, specifically configured for handling map reduce jobs via tools like Hadoop and Spark. It is pre-configured and ready to start processing your map reduce jobs.

EMR is just a service built on top of EC2 to make things like distributed map reduce jobs easier to perform. It takes away all the pain of setting up a distributed compute cluster yourself. Similar to how RDS is a managed database service built on top of EC2 that manages things like backups, read replicas and disaster recovery for you.

Comment: Does EMR provies any admin section where we could manage all EC2s in a cluster, for ex adding new EC2 or altering security setting etc ?

Comment: Your questions seem like they would be answered by a quick scan of the EMR product page. https://aws.amazon.com/emr/